# Shading a particular X variable in R boxplot ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am new to RF and really appreciate your help, In the boxplot query below, i would like to shade only g3 (most important for me), what should I add after the following code please to shade only 'g3'

```
library(ggplot2)

a<-rep(c("g1","g2","g3","g4","g5","g6"),each=10) 
b<-rnorm(60)

d1<-data.frame(a,b)

ggplot(d1)+geom_boxplot(aes(x=a,y=b))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a similar solution that allows you to customize the legend if needed.

```
library(ggplot2)

a<-rep(c("g1","g2","g3","g4","g5","g6"),each=10) 
b<-rnorm(60)

d1<-data.frame(a,b)

ggplot(d1) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=a,y=b, fill=(ifelse(a=="g3","Shaded","Not Shaded"))), show.legend = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Legend Name", values=c("grey","orange"))
```

[image]

If you want to remove the legend, just update `show.legend = FALSE`:

```
ggplot(d1) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x=a,y=b, fill=(ifelse(a=="g3","Shaded","Not Shaded"))), show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Legend Name", values=c("grey","orange"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
+ geom_boxplot(aes(x=a,y=b, fill = a == "g3")) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "green"))
```

https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/ will help you a lot to get started.

Comment: Hi Brian really appreciate your quick reply. many thanks, i actually tried it out but what is happening is that the other boxes are being shaded as red. Any way i can fix it such that rest of the boxes are unshaded but only g3 is shaded? Many thanks

Comment: I've updated the code to make it so that `g3` is highlighted and nothing else is. If you spend time looking at the resource that I linked, you would be able to figure this out on your own (and learn a lot more, as well).